# Exact Target Triggered Send using REST API, include CC and BCC Addresses

Tags: marketing-cloud, fuel-sdk

How can we send a transactional email to more than one recipients using FUEL REST Services. Using the below structure i am able to send mails to a single recipient also made a successfull batch send. still wondering how we can send CC or BCC Whats the Json structure to send a mail  one recipient.

```
    POST https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/dfa5ab87-        1b0f-e211-b71b-9c8e9920e9fc/send?access_token=...
    Content-Type: application/json
    {
    "From": {
        "Address": "code@exacttarget.com",
        "Name": "Code@"
            },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "Region": "West",
                "City": "Indianapolis",
                "State": "IN"
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE, Pravin. Please improve your question by adding in what your problem is, including any error messages you are receiving.

Comment: While we are looking to add this in the future, there currently is no way to do this.

Comment: @KellyJAndrews: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we are looking to add this in the future, there currently is no way to do this.

Comment: hi Kelly, We have got this get all the row items. but when I Put the field name like SET @Item Field(@row, "Product_Name") and publish. then i am getting an error

Comment: Create a new question, please.

Answer (score 0):

There's a beta of the Sendgrid salesforce package available that, I believe, allows you to send transactional messages. It's not exact target, but well, a bird in the hand is worth 2 on the roadmap.