# REST API cc and bcc for Triggered Send

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap, rest

Does anyone know if CC and BCC was ever added as capabilities to the SFMC REST API for Triggered Send e-mails?

The last question I could find here... [Exact Target Triggered Send using REST API, include CC and BCC Addresses](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24078/exact-target-triggered-send-using-rest-api-include-cc-and-bcc-addresses)

...mentioned that it may be on the roadmap, but I haven't found any documentation stating it's possible just yet.  I'm looking for confirmation that the capabilities do not exist, or if they do exist, the syntax of the payload.

I do see that the functionality exists in the SOAP api.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible, but it does require a little bit of setup.

1. Create a profile attribute named CCAddress (It can be anything, just using CCAddress for this example).  It is probably a good idea to mark this as Hidden so it doesn't show up on the default profile center if that is being used.
2. Modify your Triggered Email definition (Email > Interactions > Triggered Email) so that the CC field reads: `%%CCAddress%%`. You may need to pause the definition before making changes if it is running.
3. Publish changes and restart the triggered email.
4. In the REST call, pass the address that you want to receive the CC in under the SubscriberAttributes section with a key of CCAddress, example:

`{
    "From": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "Name": "example"
    },
    "To": {
        "Address": "example@example.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "example@example.com",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "CCAddress": "someaddresstoCC@example.com"
            }
        }
    } 
}`

I just tested and I can confirm that this works.  Same concept would work with BCC as well.

Comment: I have followed all the steps and unable to trigger the email. The support has said it is enabled in the account.