# How to create a REST API cc and bcc for Triggered Send, message Definition Sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

I am in the process of using a Post Rest service for Marketing Cloud messaging services, sending a transactional email using Marking Cloud triggered send functionality. I want to add a cc and a bcc parameter but I cannot figure out the proper way to do it. Originally I put the cc and the bcc function in the options sections and added an array to it, however, those users never got their email. Then, I had the same parameter value be a string only filled with 1 email however that also did not work. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CC and BCC fields are tied to the send definition, rather than the actual message send. Therefore a fixed address for every message using that triggered send definition is the case this has been designed for.

In order to do this when setting up the triggered send via the interface, you need to put one or more email addresses in (comma separated). If you don't see the fields "CC Email Address(es)" and "BCC Email Address(es)", follow step 1 of the below instructions.

If you like to configure the send definition via API, just supply the email address or comma separated list in the string properties "BccEmail" and "CCEmail".

However, you can get around this in the following way:

1. Activate the CC/BCC Option in Setup

   - Go to Setup
   - Search for "Email Optional Features"
   - "Enable" the "BCC Emails" feature
2. Add a field for CC and BCC address to the triggered send's data extension. (for my example they are named "CCAddress" and "BCCAddress" and are of type "EmailAddress")
3. Prepare the triggered send:

   - Open the triggered send definition
   - In "Send Options" set "CC Email Address(es)" to the personalization string `%%CCAddress%%`
   - In "Send Options" set "BCC Email Address(es)" to the personalization string `%%BCCAddress%%`
4. Include the CCAddress and BCCAddress in your API call within the SubscriberAttributes (JSON path "To.ContactAttributes.SubscriberAttributes.CCAddress", "To.ContactAttributes.SubscriberAttributes.BCCAddress")

Example request body:

```
{
    "To": {
        "Address": "your@email.com",
        "SubscriberKey": "yoursubscriberkey",
        "ContactAttributes": {
            "SubscriberAttributes": {
                "BCCAddress": "another@email.com",
                "CCAddress": "different@email.com"
                "OtherDataYouMightNeedForTheSend": "asdf"
            }
        }
    },
    "Options": {
        "RequestType": "SYNC"
    }
}
```

**Related documentation:**

- [SOAP API Objects - TriggeredSendDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/triggeredsenddefinition.htm)
- [Create a Triggered Email Message Interaction](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_triggered_email_interaction.htm&type=5)
- [Marketing Cloud  Setup - Email Optional Features](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_email_optional_features.htm&type=5)

Comment: Can also check out this answer as well with similar info as above (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72638/rest-api-cc-and-bcc-for-triggered-send)

Comment: Despite the toggle in Setup, I had to open a support case to get this fully enabled

Comment: For me it took a while for the options to become available after enabling the option.