# Transactional Messaging API | Add CC/BCC email address

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send, transactional-messaging-api

currently I can configure CC/BCC address while configuring the definition for Transactional Messaging API.

However the requirement is to send to additional recipients per individual email conditions via API (Example, send email to a customer, with customer's spouse in CC)

Would this be doable? or is there any workaround?

Comment: Workaround is to send the same message to multiple recipients: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/sendMessageMultipleRecipients.htm

Comment: You can also try https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/308480/how-to-create-a-rest-api-cc-and-bcc-for-triggered-send-message-definition-sends . Not sure if it'll work for transactional sends but you can give it a shot.