# Send an email to subscriber and to manager via Triggered Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, triggered-send

Is it possible to send an email to the subscriber and to another fixed address with a unique Triggered Data Extension?
I mean, I'm filling the DataExtension with two fields of type emailAddress: one for the subsriber and one for the system-manager, and I'd like to send and email to both the subscriber and system-manager, each one with its own body...

When creating the TriggeredDataExtension, how can I select witch of the two emails is the target?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although it's technically possible to create a sendable Data Extension (including a Triggered Send Data Extension) with two email address fields, using this DE for a send will result in an error and no emails will be sent:

[image]

Your best option here would be to use the CC/BCC functionality:

1. Add a text field to the TS DE called "CC" or "BCC" and fill with system manager's email address
2. In the Triggered Send setup, populate the CC/BCC fields with a personalisation string, `%%CC%%` or `%%BCC%%`. The system manager will get an exact copy of the recipient's email.

[image]

> NOTE:
>
> To enable CC & BCC feature in Marketing cloud, go to Setup > Feature
> settings > Email Studio > Email Optional Features > Enable BCC Emails.

[image]

If you're looking to send different content to both recipients, you will have to set up two separate Triggered Send Data Extensions and two emails and trigger them separately.

Reference: [https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/cc-bcc-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud#:~:text=To%20enable%20CC%20%26%20BCC%20feature,%2C%20Content%20Builder%20%26%20Triggered%20Emails](https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/cc-bcc-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20CC%20%26%20BCC%20feature,%2C%20Content%20Builder%20%26%20Triggered%20Emails).

Answer (score 4):

You can't use a sendable data extension with multiple emailaddress fields. This is why:

1. If a subscriber exists in All Subscribers list, your email will be sent to the email address which sits in All Subs for that particular Subscriber Key. Your email address fields in sendable data extension will be ignored
2. If a subscriber does not exist in All Subscribers, the email will not be sent at all, as MC will not know which email address field to use for this particular send.

You can add a CC/BCC field, as described [in this article](https://www.salesforcefan.com/post/cc-bcc-in-salesforce-marketing-cloud), so all your emails will ALSO be sent to a predefined email address:

[image]

If your CC/BCC email address is not static for all sends, here is a good thread here, on how to use a more dynamic approach, allowing you to set the CC/BCC email address in your API payload: [REST API cc and bcc for Triggered Send](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/72638/rest-api-cc-and-bcc-for-triggered-send)